# Is there a paper available on Monero?

Tags: cryptonote

Yes, I know the Monero is implemented using CryptoNight. I was, however, wondering if there is a paper that explains Monero top to bottom.

If not available, can I expect one to be published soon?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Cryptonote whitepaper jtgrassie linked, there is a paper explaining Monero at https://github.com/UkoeHB/Monero-RCT-report

Answer (score 0):

Monero is based on CryptoNote actually (CryptoNight is the PoW / hashing algorithm used).

The original CryptoNote paper (and more) can be found here: https://getmonero.org/resources/research-lab/